# Flexbox/CSS/Responsive Web Design images

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am writing a landing page using css/flexbox and I'm struggling to get some images to be equal size. The logo images I have are all different sizes and I want them to be equal size, clickable links. I was able to achieve this by creating a css table, but would really like to use flexbox, if possible.

Here is the code in question:

```css
.how-to-buy {
      /*rgba used to add opacity*/
      background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
      border: hidden;
      border-radius: 25px;
      /* make sure there is space between buttons and bottom of page */
      margin-bottom: 30px;
      padding: 10px;
      max-width: 90%;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .ebook-links img {
      border-radius: 15px;
    }

    .ebook-links img:hover {
    }

    .how-to-buy{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .ebook-links{
      max-width: 80%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .logo1{ flex: 2.07;}
    .logo2{ flex: 2.4;}
    .logo3{ flex: 3;}
    .logo4{ flex: 2.8;}
    .logo5{ flex: 2.43;}
```

```html
<div class="how-to-buy">
        <p>This collection includes nineteen tales of faeries and magic at Midwinter. Available Now online:</p>
        <div class="ebook-links">
         <a href=#>
           <img class="logo1" src="https://tinypandabird.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/amazon-logo_black-300x145.png" /></a>
         <a href=#>
          <img class="logo4" src="https://tinypandabird.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/ibooks-300x108.png" /></a>
        </div>
</div>
```

I thought that setting the logo flex values equal to their aspect ratios would work, but it doesn't seem to...

Comment: Does the height have to be flexible? If not, why not just explicitly set a max height for the logos?

Comment: Would you like them to all be equal height and width? If so, would you like them to be cropped or stretched to make them have identical size? If not, just equal height, or just equal width?

Answer (score 0):

How about you put max-height to the img tag, if you set only 'width' or only 'height' to an img tag the image does not lose the aspect ratio

```css
.how-to-buy {
      /*rgba used to add opacity*/
      background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
      border: hidden;
      border-radius: 25px;
      /* make sure there is space between buttons and bottom of page */
      margin-bottom: 30px;
      padding: 10px;
      max-width: 90%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .ebook-links img {
      border-radius: 15px;
      max-height:50px;
    }

    .ebook-links img:hover {
    }

    .how-to-buy{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .ebook-links{
      max-width: 80%;
    
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .logo1{ flex: 2.07;}
    .logo2{ flex: 2.4;}
    .logo3{ flex: 3;}
    .logo4{ flex: 2.8;}
    .logo5{ flex: 2.43;}
```

```html
<div class="how-to-buy">
        <p>This collection includes nineteen tales of faeries and magic at Midwinter. Available Now online:</p>
        <div class="ebook-links">
         <a href=#>
           <img class="logo1" src="https://tinypandabird.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/amazon-logo_black-300x145.png" /></a>
         <a href=#>
          <img class="logo4" src="https://tinypandabird.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/ibooks-300x108.png" /></a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Hope this is the result you are looking for